# Cylinder Primitive in Geometry Node is not appearing in Viewport when using the Draw tool

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've been trying to make a Geometry Node graph for creating hardware nails using a Path. In the graph, I have a cylinder primitive node that gets created and transformed to 'fit' on one of the ends of the extruded path. It appears in the original object in the viewport, but when I attempt to use the Draw tool to make a custom path, the cylinder doesn't seem to appear on the extruded path.

Geometry Node Graph:
[image]

What I see in the viewport:
[image]